# Power Automate: not recognising anchor and hence unable to extract href

Tags: html, href, anchor, power-automate

So I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZprVQbtbea0) and trying doing something similar in my power automate space. However, I am not able to get extract href option.

I have tried it multiple times and the only 3 options I get are extract text, extract ("") and Exists(True).

The only difference I am guessing is the creator of the video is getting anchor written on the top when he hovers over the text while in my case its span written. I have tried getting anchor but its not coming up.

Any solution to this? Please help.

I have tried checking for inspect page and clicking multiple times on different browsers but its not working

Comment: This is power automate desktop, correct? If so, please adjust the tag.